# Share a bluetooth keyboard between two laptops

Tags: keyboard, multiple-monitors, bluetooth

I have my sights set on a [Dell U3419W monitor](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-ultrasharp-34-curved-usb-c-monitor-u3419w/apd/210-arcl/monitors-monitor-accessories), which has built-in KVM functionality and would allow me to connect my work and personal laptops simultaneously (and switch seamlessly).

The problem is that I use a bluetooth keyboard, which I'd ideally like to share between the two laptops (both have built-in bluetooth antennas). I currently have one keyboard for each laptop, and that's a major pain.

Is there any piece of hardware that would allow me to either:

- pair the keyboard to the monitor itself, or
- allow me to pair the keyboard to said piece of hardware and the connect that to the monitor's KVM via USB?

I have not been able to find anything to help me achieve what I want, and it seems inconceivable that this cannot be easily done in 2020, when bluetooth keyboards are prevalent.

Any tips or help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Someone just pointed me to [Microsoft's Mouse Without Borders](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/mouse-without-borders-mousewithoutborders/0523308d-3406-4273-b86e-bef28aa6b50d), which gives me a software based solution to my problem.

I'd still be interested in a hardware-based solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

As product recommendations become obsolete quickly I will not list any specific hardware here. However, I think the relevant keyword is `multi device bluetooth keyboard`.

Such devices allow you to pair a single mouse/keyboard to different devices (often up to 3). By using a button on the mouse/keyboard you can select which of the 3 devices needs to be controlled.